# How to migrate NServiceBus Sagas from one Raven database to another?

Tags: ravendb, nservicebus

I need to copy several types of Sagas from one database to another. They are on the different servers. I'm going to export this with a Smuggler something like this:

```
raven.smuggler out http://localhost:8080/ dump.raven --database=Host1 --metadata-filter=Raven-Entity-Name=TestSaga
```

And then import this dump to new database.

**The question is**: Will it be safe or I need to care about additional things like indexes or something?

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to point an NServiceBus server to that, probably you do need to create indexes as well

Comment: It looks like indexes were created automatically once I imported my documents to new DB. Is it depend on some settings? I am creating steps to make migration on production environment and it can be differ

Answer (score 1):

That command export the collection "TestSaga" and also indexes and transformers (but all of them that are in your db).
If you want only documents include --operate-on-types=Documents .
I suggest you to read the [documentantion](https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/3.0/java/server/administration/exporting-and-importing-data) in particoular the section "Command line options" and the option --operate-on-types that could be right for you.

Finally i think that you need to change dump.raven to dump.ravendump